# Remotely access an EJB across a network or networks from client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, cdi

Assuming a CLI or Swing interface client, how is a remote Bean accessed through Glassfish?  By [obtaining a reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25704432/262852) the `BeanManager`?

sample code:

```
Hashtable contextArgs = new Hashtable();

// First you must specify the context factory.
// This is how you choose between jboss implementation
// vs. an implementation from Sun or other vendors.
contextArgs.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.jndiprovider.TheirContextFactory" );

// The next argument is the URL specifying where the data store is:
contextArgs.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jndiprovider-database" );

// (You may also have to provide security credentials)

// Next you create the initial context
Context myCurrentContext = new InitialContext(contextArgs);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface#Basic_lookup

So, for a CLI app to access a running glassfish app server, it would use something along the lines of:

```
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext();
        hello = (Hello) context.lookup("java:global/SalutationApp/SalutationApp-ejb/Hello");
        hello.myRemoteMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

only with a specified URL to connect to a specific glassfish instance?  How is a connection established?

Comment: Have you considered application-client for swing project? This will allow you to use the normal @EJB injection mechanism, albeit within your main class static variables.

Comment: Will. That allow multiple clienta?

Comment: Thats the purpose of ejb-application-client. Multiple clients, installs in a minute. Automatic orb configuration etc

Comment: Never saw option.  Using. NetBeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a real remote lookup, you cannot do it through the CDI's `BeanManager`, since the Swing GUI is not local.

First you need to configure the application server to allow remote calls - this most likely includes some authentication settings, but I have never done this on Glassfish.

Here is how we lookup the remote interface of our EJB bean in one of our own Swing applications that accesses a EJB deployed on JBoss 4.

First, we added a `jndi.properties` into the ClassPath of the UI, which contains the information which server is responsible for the naming lookup (note that the port number is application server specific).  This is a `jndi.properties` file used in one of our own Swing GUIs:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=server.local\:1199
```

Next, given that your naming context now knows how to lookup remote JNDI names, you can use something like this (again, this is used in our Swing UI):

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
MyRemote mr = (MyRemote) ctx.lookup("global/jndi/name/of/remote/interface");
```

Instead of using the properties file, you can also configure the InitialContext by passing config values in code, something like this:

```
    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory"); // depends on your server
    env.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://server.local:1099/");
    env.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user"); 
    env.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

This answer is not complete, but I hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: yes, I'm looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm   but not sure what JAR's I need on the classpath.

Comment: I'm going to call this complete, because it points me in the right direction and tells me what to google :)    see also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779869/remote-client-accessing-glassfish-ejb-classpath-issues